# Expo/React Navigation: simple <Link> or route.replace() doesnt work

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation, react-navigation-v6

I started a fresh expo app based on tabs template with:

**npx create-expo-app expo-tabs --template tabs**

So I changed /app/_layout.tsx to:

```
...

export const unstable_settings = {
  // Ensure that reloading on `/modal` keeps a back button present.
  initialRouteName: 'index',
};

...

function RootLayoutNav() {
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();
  // <Stack.Screen name="modal" options={{ presentation: 'modal' }} />

  return (
    <ThemeProvider value={colorScheme === 'dark' ? DarkTheme : DefaultTheme}>
      <Stack>
        <Stack.Screen name="index" options={{ title: 'Login' }} />
        <Stack.Screen name="password-recover"  options={{ title: 'Password Recovery' }} />
        <Stack.Screen name="auth" options={{ headerShown: false }} />        
      </Stack>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

And renamed the "(tabs)" folder to "auth" folder, as following:

- /app/auth/_layout.tsx (tabs layout)
- /app/auth/index.tsx (tab one)
- /app/auth/two.tsx (tab two)

The /app/auth/_layout.tsx is as following:

```
export default function TabLayout() {
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();

  return (
    <Tabs screenOptions={{ tabBarActiveTintColor: Colors[colorScheme ?? 'light'].tint, }}>
      <Tabs.Screen name="index" options={{ title: 'Tab One', }} />
      <Tabs.Screen name="two" options={{ title: 'Tab Two' }} />
    </Tabs>
  );
}
```

And this is my /app/index.tsx file:

```
export default function LoginScreen() {

  const gotoMain = () => {
    router.replace('/auth');
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>

      <Pressable onPress={gotoMain}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>Login 1</Text>
      </Pressable>

      <Link href="/auth">
        <Text style={styles.title}>Login 2</Text>
      </Link>

      <Link href="/auth/index">
        <Text style={styles.title}>Login 3</Text>
      </Link>

      <Link href="/password-recover">
        <Text style={styles.title}>Password Recover</Text>
      </Link>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Basically, what I want is a initial stack layout with login and password recovery; and after logged I want to redirect user to a tab layout (located at "auth" folder).

The problem is no login links/button (/app/index.tsx) works. When I click:

- "Login 1" - Nothing happens.
- "Login 2" - Nothing happens.
- "Login 3" - "This screen doesn't exist." ([...missing.tsx])

**What is wrong?**

According expo docs:

[image]

Really frustrated with expo/react navigation. A lot of errors, misconcepts and challenges trying to begin a simple fresh app. Even the initialize commands provided in tutorial does not work (https://docs.expo.dev/tutorial/create-your-first-app/).

**EDIT**
I got it working by removing unable_settings from main _layout.tsx:

```
export const unstable_settings = {
  // Ensure that reloading on `/modal` keeps a back button present.
  initialRouteName: 'index',
};
```

What does unable_settings.initalRouteName really means and why is it related to the reported issue?